# Oracle 11g, como agrupar datos discontinuos

Tags: plsql, oracle-11g

Estoy intentando agrupar datos de una tabla de oracle 11g, pero con mi query cuando el patron de datos no es continuo no logro obtener el resultado deseado.

| Tiempo | Pos | Estado | Fuente |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 7 | 1 | 1 |
| 11 | 7 | 1 | 1 |
| 12 | 7 | 0 | 1 |
| 13 | 7 | 0 | 1 |
| 14 | 7 | 0 | 1 |
| 15 | 7 | 1 | 1 |
| 16 | 7 | 1 | 1 |
| 17 | 7 | 1 | 1 |
| 18 | 7 | 1 | 1 |
| 19 | 7 | 1 | 2 |
| 20 | 7 | 1 | 2 |
| 21 | 13 | 1 | 2 |
| 22 | 13 | 1 | 2 |
| 23 | 13 | 1 | 2 |
| 24 | 13 | 1 | 2 |
| 25 | 19 | 1 | 2 |

De la tabla anterior quiero obtener el siguiente resultado:

| T1 | T2 | Pos | Estado | Fuente |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 11 | 7 | 1 | 1 |
| 12 | 14 | 7 | 0 | 1 |
| 15 | 18 | 7 | 1 | 1 |
| 19 | 20 | 7 | 1 | 2 |
| 21 | 24 | 13 | 1 | 2 |

Adjunto captura de pantalla de la tabla y de mi query.

Query:

```
SELECT
  POS_APILADOR,
  MIN(TO_CHAR(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) AS T1,
  MAX(TO_CHAR(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) AS T2,
  FUENTE_CHIP,
  ESTADO_APILADOR
FROM RETTIME_WPH1_INSTA
WHERE
  STATUS = 'new'
  AND
  POS_APILADOR NOT IN(
      SELECT POS_APILADOR
      FROM RETTIME_WHP1_INSTA
      WHERE RECORD_TIME = (SELECT MAX(RECORD_TIME) FROM RETTIME_WHP1_INSTA))
 GROUP BY POS_APILADOR, FUENTE_CHIP, ESTADO_APILADOR
 ORDER BY
    TI DESC;
```

Desde ya muchas gracias.

[image: Tabla origen de los datos]

[image: Query y resultado]

Comment: Ok, gracias por la sugerencia.

Comment: Y q criterio hay q tener en cuenta para que los registros salgan en esa forma q pides

Comment: Lo que necesito es obtener el tiempo de inicio y fin, agrupando primero por posicion, luego estado y por ultimo fuente.

Answer (score 0):

Con funciones de ventana. Ordenando dentro de una ventana por `tiempo`, obtén los valores del registro anterior; cuando alguno de los valores cambia ese será el registro que quieres mostrar, restando únicamente obtener el `tiempo` final trayendo el *tiempo anterior* del *cambio siguiente*.

```
SELECT r.tiempo
     , lead(r.tiempo_ant) over (order by r.tiempo) tiempo2
     , r.pos
     , r.estado
     , r.fuente
  FROM ( SELECT r.*
              , lag(pos)    over (order by tiempo) pos_ant
              , lag(estado) over (order by tiempo) estado_ant
              , lag(fuente) over (order by tiempo) fuente_ant
              , lag(tiempo) over (order by tiempo) tiempo_ant
           FROM rettime r
       ) r
  WHERE pos <> pos_ant 
     OR estado <> estado_ant 
     OR fuente <> fuente_ant 
     OR tiempo_ant is null
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Lo voy a probar y comento.